# list of figures line spacing issue

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm having this problem and have no idea how to troubleshoot it. Any thoughts?

[image]

.lof file in the area of the problem

```
    \contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline {(a)}{\ignorespaces {Equipment configuration diagram.}}}{21}{figure.caption.17}
\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline {(b)}{\ignorespaces {Thermodynamic cycle on the {\it T-s} diagram.}}}{21}{figure.caption.17}
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {4.4}{\ignorespaces Component models needed to perform the electrical portion of a DSSTC simulation.\relax }}{23}{figure.caption.18}
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\vskip -10pt
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {5.1}{\ignorespaces Parts of a solar collector performance model.\relax }}{27}{figure.caption.19}
\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline {(a)}{\ignorespaces {Solar collector model.}}}{27}{figure.caption.19}
\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline {(b)}{\ignorespaces {Irradiance model.}}}{27}{figure.caption.19}
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {6.1}{\ignorespaces Eliptical orbit of the earth around the sun.\relax }}{31}{figure.caption.20}
\vskip -10pt
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {6.2}{\ignorespaces Measures of extraterrestrial irradiance.\relax }}{32}{figure.caption.21}
\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline {(a)}{\ignorespaces {ETRN: normal to the sun.}}}{32}{figure.caption.21}
\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline {(b)}{\ignorespaces {ETR: on a horizontal surface.}}}{32}{figure.caption.21}
```

Main Document code....

```
\documentclass[colorlinks=false,12pt]{report}% ,draft draft mode places black at the right of overfull \hbox violations
% draft also does not load figures only bounding boxes for figures
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
%\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}% Russian language support
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry} % ,showframe showframe option places margins header and footer.
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.25in,bmargin=1.25in,lmargin=1.4in,rmargin=1.15in}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setlength{\maxdepth}{0pt}% May be required to prevent bottom margin violations
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage[rm, tiny,center, compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{placeins} % This package allows the command \FloatBarrier to force floats to be placed.
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure,float,wrapfig}
\graphicspath{{./figures/}}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.eps,.png,.jpg}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
%\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{tamuconfig}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, font=singlespacing]{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-exponent-marker=\ensuremath{\mathrm{e}}}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{gensymb}% \degree command
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{rotating}


\sisetup{
output-exponent-marker=\ensuremath{\mathrm{e}},
detect-weight = true,
detect-inline-weight = text
} % \num{1e-10}


% Hyperref setup below.  You should be able to get away with using uncommenting just the first line.
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% if \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} doesn't work try this.
% \usepackage{hyperref}  % Hidelinks is an option that removes link visiability.  TAMU Thesis Offices prefers to not see the links. But often doesn't work.  
% 
% \hypersetup{
%     colorlinks=true,
%     linkcolor=black,
%     citecolor=black,
%     filecolor=black,
%     urlcolor=black,
% }
%%%%%%%%  End of hyperref setup.  One of these two options should work, but my motto with hyperref is when in doubt, comment it out!

\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalise]{cleveref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% comment out for final version %%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{everypage}
%\usepackage{draftwatermark}
%\SetWatermarkText{Draft} % Do not cite
%\SetWatermarkLightness{0.8}
%\SetWatermarkScale{8}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Roman Numeral 
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\e}[2]{{#1}\mathrm{e}{#2}}
\newcommand{\simvar}{\mathord{\sim}}
\newcommand{\rmnum}[1]{\romannumeral #1}
\newcommand{\Rmnum}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}%
   \def\chapquote@author{#2}%
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax%
   \itshape}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill--\ \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% includeonly
%\includeonly{appendix/appendices}
%partsolar/transposition
%appendix/appendices
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\tamumanuscripttitle}{A new direction for distributed-scale solar-thermal co-generation}
\renewcommand{\tamupapertype}{Dissertation}
\renewcommand{\tamufullname}{Nathan Raymond Kamphuis}
\renewcommand{\tamudegree}{Doctor of Philosophy}
\renewcommand{\tamuchairone}{Kaylan Annamalai}
% Uncomment out the next line if you have co-chairs.  You will also need to edit the titlepage.tex file.
%\newcommand{\tamuchairtwo}{Andrew Duggleby}
\renewcommand{\tamumemberone}{Andrew Duggleby}
\newcommand{\tamumembertwo}{Michael Johnson}
\newcommand{\tamumemberthree}{Richard J. Malak Jr.}
\newcommand{\tamumemberfour}{David Staack}
\renewcommand{\tamudepthead}{Andreas Polycarpou}
\renewcommand{\tamugradmonth}{August}
\renewcommand{\tamugradyear}{2018}
\renewcommand{\tamudepartment}{Mechanical Engineering}


\include{0prepart/titlepage} % This is simply a file that formats and adds your titlepage, please do not edit this unless you have a specific need.
\include{0prepart/abstract}
\include{0prepart/dedication}
\include{0prepart/acknowledgements}
\include{0prepart/preface}
\include{0prepart/nomenclature}
\include{0prepart/lists}  % This is simply a file that formats and adds your toc, lof, and lot, please do not edit this unless you have a specific need.
%\include{Dissertation_NRK_test.lof} Test to trouble shoot list of figures.
\pagestyle{plain} % No headers, just page numbers
\pagenumbering{arabic} % Arabic numerals
\setcounter{page}{1}

\part{CONTEXTUALIZING THE ENERGY PROBLEM}
\label{part:energyproblem}
    \include{1partintro/introduction}
    \include{1partintro/erg}
%   \include{partintro/climatechange} added to erg
    \include{1partintro/background}
    \include{1partintro/dsstc}
```

lists.tex code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  New template code for TAMU Theses and Dissertations starting Fall 2016.  
%
%
%  Author: Sean Zachary Roberson
%  Version 3.17.09
%  Last Updated: 9/21/2017
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%       TABLE OF CONTENTS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% single-space sections in Table of Contents  - commented in version 1.7
%\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\vskip0.5\baselineskip}
%\renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\vskip0.5\baselineskip}
%\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecafterpnum}{\vskip0.5\baselineskip}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}  

\begin{singlespace}
\renewcommand\contentsname{\normalfont} {\centerline{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} % This puts \subsubsection[]{×} in your List of Tables.  The default is 3.


%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Adds Page above the page number in TOC
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{%
\hfill{\normalfont {Page}\par}}


\tableofcontents

%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill\normalfont{Page}\par\medskip}}
\end{singlespace}

\pagebreak{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                           LIST OF FIGURES
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}  

\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\center\normalfont\MakeUppercase}

\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-12pt} %% Positions the LOF title vertically to match the chapter titles
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitleskip}{12pt}


\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{%
\\[4em]\mbox{}\hspace{2pt}FIGURE\hfill{\normalfont Page}\vskip\baselineskip}

\begingroup


\begin{center}
\begin{singlespace}
%% These values make the lof table entries appear double spaced between.
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0.4cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.30cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{0.30cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{0.4cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{0.4cm}

\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.8em}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.3em}

% Provided by Andy Philips.
% needed to make chapter gaps look no different than sections:
% \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\renewcommand*\protect\addvspace[1]{}}

% Philips' document had 30 figures. Is there a maximum number of figures
% that changes the spacing to non-uniform, i.e., not double-spaced
% between all entries?

\listoffigures

\end{singlespace}
\end{center}

\pagebreak{}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                           LIST OF TABLES
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}  

\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\center\normalfont\MakeUppercase}

\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{-12pt} %% Positions the LOT title vertically to match the chapter titles

%Note that the similar parameter in the LOF is 12pt; this
%is intentional to make the spacing between the headers
%and the first entry look consistent.
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitleskip}{1pt}


\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{%
\\[4em]\mbox{}\hspace{2pt}TABLE\hfill{\normalfont Page}\vskip\baselineskip}

\begin{center}
\begin{singlespace}

%% These values make the lot table entries appear double spaced between.
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0.4cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.30cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{0.30cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{0.4cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{0.4cm}

\listoftables 

\end{singlespace}
\end{center}
\endgroup
\pagebreak{}  % Need this for the pagenumbering to be correct.
```

Comment: at the very least, it would br useful to know what document class you're using.  if i were trying to debug this, i would copy the `.lof` file, input it separately to a test file that would not overwrite it (in other words, do *not* specify `\listoffigures`), and see if the output comes out the same.  where i would look next would depend on that output.

Comment: So I updated the question with the .lof file and it looks like space is being added and subtracted in weird ways. Any ideas why things are turning out this way? Oh, I'm using the report format.

Comment: You must be using some interesting packages.  I've never seen a \l@subfigure defined before.

Comment: Something is adding  space,  and something is removing  space in the list.  What remains a mystery.  You  haven't  shown yet.

Comment: Check if the `tamu` part is relevant, if not, kick it out and merge the snippets to a compilable block.